# Python dictionary comprehension takes only last item in list for value

Tags: python

This is what I'm trying:

```
d = {num1 : num2 for num1 in range(4) for num2 in range(4,8)}
```

I thought I should get `{0 : 4, 1 : 5, 2 : 6, 3 : 7}`

What I get tho is `{0 : 7, 1 : 7, 2 : 7, 3 : 7}`

Comment: `print([(a,b) for a in range(4) for b in range(4,8)])` and see what happens

Comment: Why not just `d ={i: i+4 for i in range(4)}` ?

Comment: Because the point is using elements from 2 collections. That's a very simplified example

Answer (score 5):

If you want to iterate both ranges together, you should do it using `zip`:

```
d = {num1 : num2 for num1, num2 in zip(range(4), range(4,8))}
```

Comment: or just `dict(zip(range(4), range(4,8)))`

Comment: What I don't get is, when you do this [[a,b] for a in range (4) for b in range (4,8)] it works.. It works for generators too.. why shouldn't it work for a dictionary??

Answer (score 2):

```
a= dict(zip(range(m), range(m,n)))
print a
```

This worked for me. In you case it will be

```
a= dict(zip(range(4), range(4,8)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested comprehensions work as if the `for` loops were nested from top to bottom. Thus, your code is equivalent to -

```
d = {}
for num1 in range(4):
    for num2 in range(4,8):
        d[num1] = num2
```

Your `dict` gets updated with the latest value with each iteration, hence you get `7` in the end. You probably want what @Fernando has answered, i.e.

```
d = dict(zip(range(4), range(4,8)))
```